# Why raycast works with a reverse ray direction?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm a HOUDINI user and I know how exactly Raycast works, but in my case, something odd is happening. I think Raycast does not work correctly, when I use a reverse direction I can see the result. you can see everything in the image below:
[image]

by the way, in my case hit position does not work, it gives me zero for all points.
in the end, I checked my issue with Blender 3.4 and 3.6 and both of them are the same.

Comment: In this setup, the grid is the starting point, and the torus is the target, so $(0,0,1)$ is perfectly correct. And *hitPosition* is $0$ because you have already deleted the points one step before with `Delete Geometry`.

Comment: You mean I have to connect the torus position to the raytcast source position?

Comment: The _fields_ (rhomb sockets) are evaluated on the geometry that uses it. The "target geometry" in the raycast node is what the ray will detect intersection with. Therefore it goes up from the plane to the target deleting points on the geometry that the rays where cast from.

Comment: Thank you all.. The way Houdini raycast works is different, That's why I confused a littile